# handle new line in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have FullCalendar that for each event get data from mysql database.

```
events: [
    title: '{{sub_event.event.main_event.client.login}}',
    subtask_description: '{{sub_event.event.description}}',
],
```

when description contains new line like:

```
3
4
```

the code trows a error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

and Sorces looks like this:

```
        {
            type: 'note',
            title: 'fsfsd',
            user: 'admin',
            description: '3
4',
            start: '2020-04-04',
    },
```

Data is displayed in bootstrap modal:

```
$('#modal_subtask_description').html((event.event.extendedProps.subtask_description)
```

**Question**

How to handle new line or replace this with html br tag and set `eventRender: function(info)` to handle html tags inside bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use some JQ trick:

```
$('#modal_subtask_description').html( $('<div />').html(event.event.extendedProps.subtask_description).text());
```